# Font not loading

Tags: theme-development

I am working on a site and I'm haveing trouble viewing the font that I need for the slider I have incorporated on the front-page.

Here is the site, the arrows on the slider should appear as a font, but my font is not loading. I placed it in the CSS file.

Here is the Demo, http://zma.uk.com/zmademo

Comment: @Mayeenul Islam someone has kindly answered, do I delete this question now? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted more info about this but i can't comment here because i don't have enough reputation, i may have a solution for you.

First, your font `flexslider-icon` works, but your media queries hide it on screen with more than *860px*.

On screens more than *860px* arrows become transparent and move out of slider. Here it's a simple solution.

**Make always visible:**

*On `flexslider.css` Replace:*

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: -50px;
    text-align: right;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: -50px;
}
```

*with this:*

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 1;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```